# Integrating Databricks SQL Connector with Django ORM for CRUD Operations

Tags: python, django, databricks, django-orm, databricks-sql

I am working on a Django project that requires integration with Databricks, and I am currently exploring the use of the [databricks-sql-connector](https://pypi.org/project/databricks-sql-connector/) Python package for connectivity. However, my concern is that utilizing this package might involve manual SQL query creation for CRUD operations within my Django project.

Is there a method available that allows me to establish a connection to the Databricks database while still leveraging Django's ORM capabilities? I would like to achieve a connection similar to the following code snippet:

```py
sql.connect(
    server_hostname=connection_params["hostname"],
    http_path=connection_params["http_path"],
    access_token=connection_params["access_token"]
)
```

Additionally, I would like to extract a cursor using the following snippet:

```py
connections["default"].cursor()
```

My database settings are configured as follows:

```py
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'custom_engine_name',
        'HOSTNAME': os.getenv('DATABRICKS_HOSTNAME'),
        'NOTEBOOK_PATH': os.getenv('DATABRICKS_NOTEBOOK_PATH'),
        'ACCESS_TOKEN': os.getenv('DATABRICKS_ACCESS_TOKEN'),
    }
}
```

My expectation is to find a method or solution that allows me to establish a connection to the Databricks database using Django's ORM, avoiding the need for manual SQL queries. If this requires writing a custom adapter, I would appreciate guidance on how to create one that effectively connects Django ORM with the "databricks-sql-connector."